# list indices must be integers or slices, not str error Python

Tags: python, dictionary

My code is below. This is code for parsing links from urls. I have dictonary of 2 urls:

```py
newsurls = {'Kommersant': 'https://www.kommersant.ru/RSS/news.xml',
            'Vesti': 'https://www.vesti.ru/vesti.rss'}


class News:
    def __init__(self, rss_dict):
        self.rss_dict = rss_dict
        self.parseRSS()
        self.get_links()

    def parseRSS(self):
        for key, url in self.rss_dict.items():
            return feedparser.parse(url)

    def get_links(self):

        allfeed = []
        for key, url in newsurls.items():
            feed = News.parseRSS(self)
            allfeed.extend(feed)

        links = []

        alllinks = []

        for newsitem in allfeed['items']:
            links.append(newsitem['link'])

        for key, url in self.rss_dict.items():
            alllinks.extend(links)
        self.alllinks = alllinks

        for l in alllinks:
            print(l)


News(newsurls)
```

I have error `TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str` in line `for newsitem in allfeed['items']:`

i think i have problem cause it's `list` of `dictonaries`, how can i optimize this code?

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-43-7e99e79bbd4b> in <module>()
----> 1 News(newsurls)

<ipython-input-42-a003b05ebeb5> in __init__(self, rss_dict)
      3         self.rss_dict = rss_dict
      4         self.parseRSS()
----> 5         self.get_links()
      6 
      7 

<ipython-input-42-a003b05ebeb5> in get_links(self)
     22         alllinks = []
     23 
---> 24         for newsitem in allfeed['items']:
     25             links.append(newsitem['link'])
     26 

TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you are getting this is error is because `allfeed` is a list as defined on line 17 (`allfeed = []`). To fix it simply replace

```
for newsitem in allfeed['items']:
```

with

```
for newsitem in allfeed:
```

Comment: have this error now 
`TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-50-7e99e79bbd4b> in <module>()
----> 1 News(newsurls)

----> 5         self.get_links()
      6 
      7 

<ipython-input-49-ea0353f84243> in get_links(self)
     23 
     24         for newsitem in allfeed:
---> 25             links.append(newsitem['link'])
     26 
     27         for key,url in self.rss_dict.items():

TypeError: string indices must be integers`

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit hard to make sense of what you're trying to do, but I think it's this:

```
    links = []
    for key, url in self.rss_dict.items():
        feed = feedparser.parse(url)
        for newsitem in feed['items']:
            links.append(newsitem['link'])
```

Answer (score 0):

```
alllinks = []

for newsitem in allfeed['items']:
```

above are culprit lines, either defined

```
alllinks = {}
```

or use

```
for newsitem in allfeed
```